# Cannot verify solution provided by DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

Below is my Mathematica code to solve a system of partial differential equations. In my attempt to verify the solution (shown below), it seems to me that the solution satisfies `eqn2`, but not `eqn1`.  Any suggestions on what went wrong?

```
eqn1 = D[\[Psi][t, x], t] == (\[Alpha] - 2)/4 - k[x*t]; 
eqn2 = D[\[Psi][t, x], x] == -0.5; 
sol = \[Psi][t, x] /. DSolve[{eqn1, eqn2}, \[Psi][t, x], {t, x}]
D[sol, t]
D[sol, x]
Simplify[%]
```

Comment: The command of Maple `pdsolve({diff(psi(t, x), t) = (alpha - 2)/4 - k(x*t), diff(psi(t, x), x) = -1/2}, psi(t, x))` performs "Warning: System is inconsistent".

Comment: Maybe that is correct.  Shouldn't Mathematica say something like that?

Comment: In fact,  `D[\[Psi][t, x], x] == -1/2` implies (if I am not mistaken) `\[Psi][t,x]==-1/2*x+F[t]`, but`F'[t]!=k[t*x]`.

Comment: Yes,  correct!  Ok, then D[\[Psi][t, x], t] =F'[t] and then  must have F'[t]=(\[Alpha] - 2)/4 - k[x*t].  Inconsistent!

Comment: You try to solve two(!) pde 's  for one(!)  unknown function  ` \[Psi][t, x]`! Impossible I think.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  Agree. That is why I thought at first they wanted to solve the PDE's separately but they wrote it in one command instead. This is no different than solving two equations for one variable.   May be Mathematica should just returned `{}` in this case?

Comment: I am asking is there a  function with given partial derivatives!  Not always true.! See above!

Comment: @Nasser DSolve doesn't evaluate and gives no hint...

Comment: Does anyone know what are the criteria for a function to have prescribed partial derivatives?

Comment: Ulrich Neumann and complex see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem) for info.